# How to get rid of Ubuntu Grub

Tags: dual-boot, permanent-delete

Gnu grub version 2.02 beta2-9 Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

That's what comes up when I turn on my computer after deleting the Ubuntu partitions when I decided to get rid of it. If I type exit in the command line that comes up, it brings me to the windows boot manager and I can get to windows, but how do I get rid of the grub thing. Please help me fix this problem and be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that grub is still installed in the MBR of the drive. Deleting the partitions does nothing to the MBR as it's in a separate reserved location. You can eliminate it by simply using your Windows installation and recovery disk to re-write the MBR How this works exactly may vary slightly dependant upon the version of Windows you are using. The recovery console commands `fixboot` and `fixmbr` come to mind.

Comment: I tried that and it did nothing. When i googled how to delete grub, others had he problem of grub rescue and what you suggested worked only for that. fixboot and fixmbr didn't work for me. By the way, I have windows 8.1 and might it be a problem that i deleted the partitions before I attemped to remove the grub.

Comment: That's odd. When you installed grub where did you install it?

Comment: I will tr again and see if i did something wrong. By the way, I am using a recovery USB I created for this.

Comment: where the MBR lives depends on the partitioning scheme in use..

Comment: If your system has EFI instead of BIOS I think a seperate EFI boot partition is used for GRUB2 and not the MBR.

Comment: exactly what I was getting at @quassy GPT is indeed different: More here: https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Some_basics_of_MBR_v/s_GPT_and_BIOS_v/s_UEFI

Comment: I have EFI, so can anyone explain to me how to get rid of grub or direct me somewhere that can please?

Comment: Again, Where did you install grub originally? Did you install it in a /boot/efi partition?

Comment: I don't know where grub was installed. I did a Ubuntu/Windows 8.1 dual boot by installing ubuntu to a new partition, which I deleted.

Comment: This says BIOS but really is UEFI,: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi And if UEFI, you should just be able to go into UEFI boot tab and move Windows entry to first boot option.

Comment: That says i must do itin Ubuntu. I deleted ubuntu

Comment: Thanks everyone, I really appreciate you all trying, but I found the solution on another forum. It didn't work for the person who asked for the help, but I gave it try and it worked great! I downloaded Visual BCD as suggested in the other forum and selected Ubuntu and deleted it. Here's the  [forum](http://www.eightforums.com/installation-setup/49099-remove-grub-bootloader-fixmbr-fixboot-not-working-2.html)